# XPath reverse lookup

Tags: xpath

Given a list of XPath query and a node in the XML document, I need to find out all XPath queries that matches the node.
The simplest way is to go through each XPath query and match the node. But I am looking for faster way of doing this. Is there any existing library/tools in .NET (or any platform)?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just use**:

```
count(yourExpression | $theNode) = count(yourExpression)
```

**Substitute `"yourExpression"` with any of your expressions and `$theNode` with an XPath expression that selects exactly this node, then take these for which the result is**:

`true()`

In .NET the way to evaluate any XPAth 1.0 expression is to call the [**`XPathNavigator.Evaluate()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx) method.

**Remember**:  Node-set membership (both in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0) can be expressed as:

```
count($node-set | $node) = count($node-set)
```

**XPath 2.0 solution:**

```
yourExpression intersect $theNode is $theNode
```

**or just**:

```
boolean(yourExpression intersect $theNode)
```